# Symfony2: Dependency injection reliant on request

Tags: php, symfony, dependency-injection, proxy-classes

**Preamble**

My Symfony2 application will be accessed from several TLD's. Depending on the TLD I want to use a different swiftmailer mailer. I however failed to dynamically inject the correct mailer despite trying a multitude of approaches (service factory, compiler pass, DI extension, "dynamic alias").

This lead to a fundamental realisation: Dependencies are injected **before** the container is compiled, the request is available **after** the container is compiled. Hence there is no way to make dependency injection reliant on the request (and therefore all above-mentioned approaches failed).

**Problem**

I was told never to pull dependencies, but to always inject them.

To illustrate this further:

I have

- [three swiftmailers](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/swiftmailer.html#using-multiple-mailers): mailer_en, mailer_de, mailer_ie and
- three domains: domain.co.uk, domain.de and domain.ie

and want to inject the correct swiftmailer into a [custom mailer service for FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/gimler/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/emails.md#using-a-custom-mailer) (or into any other service that needs swiftmailer).

**Question**

**How do I inject the correct dependency if I don't know it until the request is available?**

I had two ideas, but not sure as to how suitable they are:

1. Should I inject some kind of "Mailer Provider"? Still kind of pulling dependencies, isn't it?
2. Can I use some kind of proxy class, forwarding interaction to the correct emailer?

Or am I completely on the wrong route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Injecting the request [is covered in the documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/service_container.html#book-container-request-stack). That being said, I think you'll get the most bang for the buck [by using a factory](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/factories.html).

Answer (score 1):

For future reference, here is the **implementation of [Peter's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30620129/symfony2-dependency-injection-reliant-on-request/30620741#30620741)**:

[Custom mailer for FOSUserBundle](https://github.com/gimler/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/emails.md) config:

```
# app/config/config.yml

fos_user:
    # ...
    service:
        mailer: acme.mailer
```

and

```
# src/Acme/UserBundle/config/services.xml

<service id="acme.mailer.factory" class="Acme\UserBundle\Service\TwigSwiftMailerFactory" public="false">
    <call method="setContainer">
        <argument type="service" id="service_container" />
    </call>
</service>

<service id="acme.mailer" class="TwigSwiftMailer">
    <factory service="propeo_user.mailer.factory" method="createTwigSwiftMailer" />
    <argument type="service" id="acme.mailer_name_provider" />
    <argument type="service" id="router" />
    <argument type="service" id="twig" />
    <argument type="collection">
        <argument key="template" type="collection">
            <argument key="confirmation">%fos_user.registration.confirmation.template%</argument>
            <argument key="resetting">%fos_user.resetting.email.template%</argument>
        </argument>
    </argument>
</service>
```

as well as the factory class:

```
# Acme/UserBundle/Service/TwigSwiftMailerFactory

class TwigSwiftMailerFactory extends ContainerAware
{
    private function getContainer()
    {
        if(!($this->container instanceof ContainerInterface)) {
            throw new \RuntimeException('Container is missing');
        }
        return $this->container;
    }

    public function createTwigSwiftMailer(MailerNameProvider $mailerNameProvider, UrlGeneratorInterface $router, \Twig_Environment $twig, array $parameters)
    {
        $container = $this->getContainer();
        $name = $mailerNameProvider->getMailerName(); // returns mailer name, e.g. mailer_en

        $mailer = $container->get(
            sprintf('swiftmailer.mailer.%s', $name ? $name : 'default')
        );

        $parameters['from_email']['confirmation'] =
            $parameters['from_email']['resetting'] =
                $container->getParameter(
                    sprintf('swiftmailer.mailer.%s.sender_address', $name ? $name : 'default')
                )
        ;

        return new TwigSwiftMailer($mailer, $router, $twig, $parameters);
    }
}
```